# How I do exclude 0 when using MIN with an IF?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook with 2 worksheets, `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`.

`Sheet1` has a value (product code) to look up, and an empty cell to fill:

```
A      B
A100
A200
B150
C3AB
```

`Sheet2` has a bunch of product codes and costs:

```
A      B
A100   35
A100   14
A100    0
A200   10
A200   12
etc, etc, etc
```

I'm using the following formula in Sheet1 B1 to find the MIN matching value from Sheet2:

```
=MIN(IF(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5=A1,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$5))
```

How can I also exclude returning a match of 0? In the case of product A100, I would want to return the lowest non-zero match which would be 14.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try submitting this as an array formula in B1

*untested*

```
=MIN(IF(((Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5=A1)*(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$5>0))>0,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$5))
```

I think This Will work

Comment: Thanks, but that still found the MIN value of 0

Comment: @scott this will work for **limited** ranges, but what about a long list in B?

Comment: It should work as long as you don't eat up all your memory (especially in '03), if the list is so long in B that the formula takes too much memory he should probably use vba and not a formula

Comment: @scott The worksheet can have 20000 rows. The version is Excel 2007. I've been reading things on VBA all morning. I can hack together a C# program, but haven't done much with VBA.

Comment: It might take a little while to calculate, but if you're only doing it once, just copy the new column and paste them as values, other than that if it is too slow for you, you should look into a vba solution

Comment: It's probably marginally more efficient to use two IFs rather than multiplying with *, i.e. `=MIN(IF(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5=A1,IF(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$5>0,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$5)))`

Answer (score 2):

Would it be any faster if you add column C on Sheet 1 and fill it with:

```
=IF(B1=0," ",B1)
```

Then your original formula entered as a matrix would work referencing column C instead:

```
=MIN(IF(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5=A1,Sheet2!$C$1:$C$5))
```

Can anyone comment on the speed of adding another column? It sounds like the sheet has up to ~20000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Array formula:

```
{=SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$5<>0;IF(A3=Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5;Sheet2!$B$1:$B$5;"");"");1)}
```

Shift-Ctrl-Enter in formula window to insert, curled brackets are inserted by Excel, not by a user.

`MIN`behaved strangely, issuing `0`also for non-numeric values in the array. `SMALL` was used instead, giving `#NUM!` error for non-existing references.

Example spreadsheet: http://www.bumpclub.ee/~jyri_r/Excel/MInimal_value_excluding_0.xls

Comment: AND doesn't work here because AND always returns a single result rather than the array that you need in these sort of formulas

Comment: @barryhoudini: You are right. Sometimes Friday nights are bad for correct thinking ;)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK: Either use VBA to loop through the values, or:

create another column using a formula similar to `=IF(a1=0,"",A1)` (copied down for each value in column A). Then you can use the min function on this column.

HTH